# Assigning variables dynamically in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, numpy

I have initialised a numpy array as:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('rand1.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.int)
```

After importing, 'data' looks like:

```
array([[422, 858, 129, 312,  79, 371],
       [ 39, 280, 366,  13, 316,  81],
       [929,  49, 909, 734, 635, 779],
       [365, 570, 863, 108, 545, 846],
       [150, 820, 193, 373, 865, 770],
       [486, 547, 759,  56, 413, 470],
       [322, 171, 463, 998, 351,  92],
       [690, 297, 558, 476,  60, 804]])
```

Now I am trying to store each of these array items in different variables. That is, if my array is nxm, there should be nm different variables.
The code I am using is :

```
for x in range(0,8):
    for y in range(0,6):
        str(x)+str(y)=data[x,y]
```

But, it is giving me an error saying

> "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"

.
Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here and how should it be done?

Comment: "Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here" - the whole idea is absurd. don't do that.

Comment: Would you mind telling why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't help people do stupid things.

Comment: This is disappointing. I am a novice here and I want to do something. If my way of doing that is "absurd", experts here should at least tell me the right way of doing it. You are not helping me learn anything here.

Comment: just use the array as it is. you don't need intermediate variables.

Comment: The reason is, I am not able to pass this array as an argument in a function. I just want to pass first row of this array as an argument in optimize.newton(func, 5102, args="first row here"). But I am not able to do so. I will appreciate any help here.

Comment: delete this question, post a new one, explaining what you're really trying to do. "how do I get the first row". and, perhaps, google before posting...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I get the point you're trying to make here. The tone is overly aggressive, however. That this might happen often on SO is no reason to take it out on a new user (Why should they come back when their first impression is this negative?). But, I do agree that the question should be restated.

Comment: I agree with both of you, i will do the need full here. Thanks.

Comment: "Now I am trying to store each of these array items in different variables." Why?

Comment: [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

Comment: I've never used Numpy, but if arrays are like Python lists, then `data[0]` should give you the first row, so your call can be written as `optimize.newton(func, 5102, args = data[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Python is indeed a dynamic language, and with many efforts you could find a way to dynamically create variables. But please don't ever try :

- it would be useless since you can access the value with the syntax data[x, y]
- it would be hard to use anywhere else in your code, since you might not exactly know the number of those dynamic variables.

If you do not want to use a numpy array, you could use a list of lists. But please do not try to create variables at run-time it would really be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Well.. the closest thing would be `key` assignment in a dictionary. It's a fairly legitimate way of creating 'dynamic' variables, although it's obviously safer and, more importantly, contained.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments and other answer, this is a *bad* idea and very likely an XY problem. That being said, it *is* strictly possible:

```
globals()[str(x)+str(y)] = data[x, y]
```

This works because `globals()` returns a dict which maps module-level variable names (stored as strings) to their respective objects. You need to use that dict because otherwise you're trying to do something like:

```
'foo' = 'bar'
```

which you shouldn't expect to be valid.

As written, this is especially brittle and pointless. The strings you're constructing are purely numeric, and hence not valid variable names. That means you can only get to them by looking them up in `globals()`. This could be mitigated by putting a letter or word on the front of them, so

```
globals()['data'+str(x)+str(y)] = data[x, y]
```

And then you could access them by `print(data00)` and so on.

Please don't actually do this.

Comment: I don't mean to sound repetitive about this... but nowhere does the OP explicity say they want to pollute the global namespace with dynamically generated variables. The only part that's true is the OP's desire to create variables dynamically, which is perfectly do-able with a user-defined dictionary. I'm not saying it's the solution for this particular problem, but it's perfectly sensible to write  'foo' = 'bar' when doing myOwnDict['foo'] = 'bar'. While it's a good thing to warn a novice about using globals(), it probably would have been even better to say, 'Here, create your own dictionary'.